# Cannot get the left image with bumblebee2 camera by "bumblebee1394" package

Tags: ros, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
There some confusion for me by [bumblebee1394](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=bumblebee1394), that i always cannot get the left image.

I try

```
$ roscore
$ coriander
$ rosrun bumblebee1394 bumblebee1394
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/dcam_1300157075816067926/left/image_raw
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/dcam_1300157075816067926/right/image_raw
```

where there always get the same image which is published by right camera. And I read the code carefully that i cannot get any idea. Have somebody faced this problem by bumblebee2 camera?

and for more, when I command `$ rosrun bumblebee1394 bumblebee1394`
that the terminal show:

```
~$ rosrun bumblebee1394 bumblebee1394 
[dcam] Reset bus
[dcam] Initializing camera, turning off ISO
[dcam] Color device
[Dcam] Setting type of video mode to 1047752033
[Dcam] Feature register hi: ff9d0000
[Dcam] Feature register lo: 40000000
[Dcam] Exposure min/max: [1,1023]
[Dcam] Gain min/max: [0,683]
[Dcam] Brightness min/max: [0,255]
[Dcam] Setting type of video mode to 75
left imagebumblebee_optical_frame
right imagebumblebee_optical_frame
```

which I only get the mono image, could somebody explain  to me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9417/cannot-get-the-left-image-with-bumblebee2-camera-by--%22bumblebee1394%22-package/) by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the bumblebee stereo camera only transmits stereo images when configured to send images in format7 mode3.

about the second part, the node bumblebee1394 loads a number of parameters from the parameter server. if you start the node with the command: "rosrun bumblebee1394 bumblebee1394" you start it with its default parameters. this means it takes iso speed 400, 30 fps and 640x480 mono 8 bit images.
the bumblebee1394 folder also contains a launch file which you can use as example on now to set you own settings on the parameter server.

---

Originally posted by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) with karma: 241 on 2011-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) on 2011-06-06**:
the bumblebee2 node sets the values for rectification(done by stereo_image_proc(http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc)) hard coded in the function: updateBumblebee2CalibrationData(). stereo_image_proc uses the calibration set in the CameraInfo message.

**Comment by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on 2011-05-31**:
Thanks u, and for my first question. How to get the rectification stereo images to do process follow-up? i found some ros-packages which turned out all to be failed. I decided to get the right rectification image which by bumblebee2 itself or not ROS. Do u have some ideas about it?